# ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE Intent puts text under every picture while sharing multiple pictures on whatsapp in android

Tags: android

I am sharing multiple images like this

```
    val shareIntent = Intent()
    shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm sharing multiple images")
    shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photos)
    shareIntent.type = "image/*"
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share..."))
```

its working fine, but problem is that when I share it on whatsapp it shows text under every picture. Is there any approach which can help me share multiple images and just puts text under one picture while sharing on whatsapp

Comment: Did you try with an array list? What did you try?

Comment: @blackapps yes, `photos` is actually `ArrayList<Uri>`

Comment: My god.. yes i had seen that of course. Now think again.

Comment: @blackapps what do you mean?

Comment: You were complaining about the same text. So it was for your texts. You supply only one text.

Comment: @blackapps I am passing text just once and passing arrayList of Uri of pictures...is there any issue in that?

Comment: Your issue was that your single text was below your multiple images i thought.